# How Base classes are automatically instantiated before derived classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance

I want to know how Base classes are automatically instantiated before derived classes when we created derived class's instance.

I just want to know how base class's members occupied memory and child class's references access them.

Answer (score 3):

Lets have some examples:

```
class A
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

class B: A
{
    int c;
}
```

If you create a new instance of `A`, a piece of memory is create on the heap. This memory will be occupy 8 bytes; 4 bytes for `x` and 4 bytes for `y`. (I know, much more memory is reserved for its type, etc. but I will leave that outside this scope).

If you create a new instance of `B`, anohter piece of memory is created. Not two, only one. So no child instances or whatsoever. This piece of memory will by 12 bytes in length (4 bytes for `x`, 4 bytes for `y` and 4 bytes for the new field `z`.

When a piece of memory is created on the heap, it will always be filled with zero's. So all fieds will have their default value, in this case `0`.

If both classes would have a public parameterless constructor, these constructors are called automatically.

```
class A
{
    int x;
    int y;
    public A()
    {
        x = 1; y = 2;     
    }
}

class B: A
{
    int c;
    public B()
    {
        z = 3;
    }
}
```

When a new instance of `B` is created, the constructor of `B` is called. The first thing that constructor does is call constructor of `A`. `A` will set its fields `x` and `y` to `1` and `2`. Then the program returns to the constructor of `B` who will initialize `z` with the value `3`.

The constructor of `B` could also have been written as (to show that `B` is calling the constructor of its base `A`):

```
    public B()
        : base()
    {
        z = 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The object is *created* all at once: the space for the fields is allocated based on the knowledge that `X : Y : Z` needs space for the sum of fields declared in `X`, `Y`, `Z` (and any `object` overhead, as the implicit base of `Z`). The fields are inherited, so an `X` *is* a `Z`.

They are initialized from the bottom-up because *that is how the constructors work*; if we write:

```
class A : B
{
    private int _a = 1;
    public A() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
class B {
    private int _b = 1;
    public B() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}
```

then we get (for `B`):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0002: stfld int32 B::_b
    L_0007: ldarg.0 
    L_0008: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    L_000d: ldstr "B"
    L_0012: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0017: ret 
}
```

and for `A`:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0002: stfld int32 A::_a
    L_0007: ldarg.0 
    L_0008: call instance void B::.ctor()
    L_000d: ldstr "A"
    L_0012: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0017: ret 
}
```

note it calls the base-constructor **before** running its own local constructor code. Note also that field-initializers come even before that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation to this is think inheritance as Copy Machine

So lets define 2 classes

```
class Base
{
}

class Child : Base
{
}
```

Now you want to create an object of child. Child has its own fields but since it inherits from base, it has to go and copy all the fields of its base class and hence automatic creation.

Classes are templates for object, inheritance is nothing but resuable templates that you could attach while creating new templates.

Comment: It doesn't "copy" all the fields as such - it inherits them; they are *the same fields*

Comment: But isnot inheriting a mere act of copying the template of the base class ?

Comment: No. That would make the private fields available

Comment: Private fields are still available if we cast the object in to its base class. My point is, there is only one big Object which is being created. Is not the case ?

Comment: @Anand there is no such thing as "an object". That is an abstract term that we use to mean "a block of memory to which we put meaning". As far as that meaning goes, we are simply assigning hypothetical names (the runtime won't even use the names) to offsets from an address. It is tricky to say that the subclass is in some way "copied" from the base-class - it merely becomes the superset of offsets. But that is no different to using the base-class directly.